# Inverse search seems glitchy in sublime text 4 + latextools

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sublime-text, latextools, evince

Inverse search, in evince using latextools, seems to work for some files but doesn't work for some and usually opens a blank document in sublime text 4. Also, forward search and Ctrl+l works as expected.

Some of the things that I've done:

- ran `check system`: no issues there
- uninstalled and reinstalled latextools

P.S. I using ubuntu 20.04.